# How do I integrate this natural logarithmic function?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$ \int 5 \mathrm{ln}(x^{1/3}) dx$$
Working with natural log is very unfamiliar to me (I think I was cheated in my Calc 1 course). I know that integrating $\frac{1}{x} = \ln x$, but is it the same in reverse? Also would this simply be $u$ - substitution or instead integral by parts?

Help is so very appreciated!

Comment: $\ln x^a=a\ln x$ and $\ln x=1\cdot \ln x+x\cdot \frac{1}{x}-1$

Answer (score 6):

First, clean it up a bit using some properties of logarithms:

$$5 \ln{x^{1/3}} = 5 \left(\frac 1 3 \ln{x}\right) = \frac 5 3 \ln{x}$$

Now in order to integrate $\ln$, try going by parts with $u = \ln{x}$ and $dv = dx$. This gives

$$\int \ln{x} dx = x \ln{x} - \int x \frac{dx}{x}$$

Comment: Tip: the anti derivative of ln x is xlnx - x, as Bongers pointed out.  Memorize this anti derivative. It comes back loooots of times when doing integration with transcedental functions. I almost would rather say, it's a standard anti derivative...

Comment: I agree with @imranfat. Knowing that $\int \ln x \ dx = x \ln x - x + C$ is handy--comes up quite frequently, especially in Differential Equations (and in Calc 2, which I presume you're in now--pops up a lot in IBP problems).

Comment: I respectfully disagree.  You can integrate $\ln x$ the same way you integrate $x^r \ln x$ for any real $r$ (except the anomolous $r = -1$).  It's nice to know its antiderivative, but it's so easy to find on the fly, I wouldn't push anyone to memorize it.  Chacun a son gout.

Comment: Yeah, pushing is perhaps too much. But that anti derivative just occurs in a lot. I happen to teach this kind of calculus and my students can use reference pages. But I am always delighted that when I am lecturing andthis integral comes around the corner, that a student just states its anti derivative before anyone else has even a chance to look it up or calculate. In my days, we had to memorize all this stuff (including reduction formulas), no reference pages, nothing...

Answer (score 1):

You can also substitute away $\mathrm{ln}x$ altogether. You will then end up with the well known integral $xe^x$, kind of the introductory example of Integration by Parts.

Considering your earlier post about $x\mathrm{cos}(6x)$, I may have the inclination that you have seen this integral before. Back-substitute gives the anti-derivative from Bongers.